# Tags for Android-related API versions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What should be the right structure for Android API-related tags?

I found tags like [android-1.6](/questions/tagged/android-1.6) and [cupcake](/questions/tagged/cupcake) which is an alias of API4. Also I found the tag [android-sdk-2.3](/questions/tagged/android-sdk-2.3). Shouldn't be there some more uniform tags? Like Android-API-1.0, Android-API-1.1, etc. and also to add some aliases to find them faster?

[See also this list of Android names, platform names and API versions.](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)

I would like to suggest to enfoce the usage of tags with the prefix "android-". I already created some tags and changed many tags.

- [eclair](/questions/tagged/eclair) -> [android-eclair](/questions/tagged/android-eclair)
- [froyo](/questions/tagged/froyo) -> [android-froyo](/questions/tagged/android-froyo)

Comment: Note that [tag:cupcake] seems to be used mostly for a forum plugin for CakePHP. Need some disambiguation there.

Comment: If I scroll down your link there seems to be much more android related questions.