# Merge and synonymize Android version tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We don't need two separate tags for the same thing...

[cupcake](/questions/tagged/cupcake), [android-cupcake](/questions/tagged/android-cupcake) `-->` [android-1.5](/questions/tagged/android-1.5)

[donut](/questions/tagged/donut), [android-donut](/questions/tagged/android-donut) `-->` [android-1.6](/questions/tagged/android-1.6)

[eclair](/questions/tagged/eclair), [android-eclair](/questions/tagged/android-eclair) `-->` [android-2.0](/questions/tagged/android-2.0)

[android-froyo](/questions/tagged/android-froyo) `-->` [android-2.2](/questions/tagged/android-2.2)

[gingerbread](/questions/tagged/gingerbread), [android-gingerbread](/questions/tagged/android-gingerbread) `-->` [android-2.3](/questions/tagged/android-2.3) (I just killed this one because there were so few)

[honeycomb](/questions/tagged/honeycomb) `-->` [android-3.0](/questions/tagged/android-3.0)

[ice-cream-sandwich](/questions/tagged/ice-cream-sandwich) `-->` [android-4.0](/questions/tagged/android-4.0)

They should all use the **version number** tags to match the rest of the site.

All of the **android-** prefix tags should be **synonymized**.

All of the **plain-name** tags should be **destroyed**.

Comment: Yeah, those codename tags are horrible.

Comment: Possible dublicate of [Tags for Android-related API versions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122538/171881).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is finally done. Results:

- [android-1.5](/questions/tagged/android-1.5) ← [cupcake](/questions/tagged/cupcake), [android-cupcake](/questions/tagged/android-cupcake)
- [android-1.6](/questions/tagged/android-1.6) ← [android-donut](/questions/tagged/android-donut)

  **Note:** [donut](/questions/tagged/donut) was destroyed due to ambiguity with [donut-chart](/questions/tagged/donut-chart)
- [android-2.0](/questions/tagged/android-2.0) ← [eclair](/questions/tagged/eclair), [android-eclair](/questions/tagged/android-eclair)
- [android-2.2](/questions/tagged/android-2.2) ← [froyo](/questions/tagged/froyo), [android-froyo](/questions/tagged/android-froyo)
- [android-2.3](/questions/tagged/android-2.3) ← [gingerbread](/questions/tagged/gingerbread), [android-gingerbread](/questions/tagged/android-gingerbread)
- [android-3.0](/questions/tagged/android-3.0) ← [honeycomb](/questions/tagged/honeycomb), [android-honeycomb](/questions/tagged/android-honeycomb)
- [android-4.0](/questions/tagged/android-4.0) ← [ice-cream-sandwich](/questions/tagged/ice-cream-sandwich), [android-ics](/questions/tagged/android-ics)

  **Note:** [android-ics](/questions/tagged/android-ics) synonym was added to help [disambiguate with iCalendar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188442)
- [android-4.2](/questions/tagged/android-4.2) ← [jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/jelly-bean), [android-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/android-jelly-bean)

Comment: The fragmentation! God save us all!

Comment: You're turning out to be a decent mod, animuson!

Comment: I think [jellybean] should be synonymized as well, but about this topic I think http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203969/how-to-handle-jellybean-tag-with-respect-to-android-4-2-and-android-4-3 is relevant.