# Mark iCalendar, ics, and ical tags as synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The iCalendar, ical, and ics tags are applied to questions covering the same basic topic: the iCalendar format.  Is there a meaningful distinction between them, or should they be marked as synonyms?  I don't have sufficient reputation (or expertise on the topic).  Can someone with more expertise weigh in?

Comment: Technically, AFAIK, “iCal” is an application from Apple whereas the other two are the name and the file extension of a data format (which iCal uses); other calendar software uses iCalendar as well.

Comment: Apple's application does use that name, but consider: 1) the "ical" tag description mentions the iCalendar format but not the Apple iCal application, and 2) a quick review of questions with the "ical" tag found many questions related to the iCalendar standard but none related to the Apple iCal application.  I think an iCal tag concerning the application would be useful, but people don't seem to use it that way.  They treat it as a synonym for iCalendar and ics.

Comment: I was about to ask a meta question about the same thing.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888380/icalendar-rfc5545-recurrence-rule-multiple-times-a-day) that is tagged as both iCalendar and ical.  Either the ical description should change or the tags should be merged.

Answer (score 2):

I've gone ahead and approved the existing [icalendar](/questions/tagged/icalendar) ← [ical](/questions/tagged/ical) synonym that was in the system and also created the [icalendar](/questions/tagged/icalendar) ← [ics](/questions/tagged/ics) synonym. I didn't merge them, just in case. Let's see how it plays out.

Comment: Err...wasn't there some questions tagged "ics" that were referring to "Ice Cream Sandwich" (aka Android v4.0)? I seem to recall a question about that here. (Searching now.)

Comment: Ah. [Found it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164366/three-tags-used-for-2-topics-ics-ice-cream-sandwich-and-icalendar). They were fixed.

Comment: @AlEverett: I thought about that too, but I didn't see any when I browsed over them before making the synonym. I figure at some point the [tag:ics] tag should get merged over and deleted since it's ambiguous.

Comment: @AlEverett: Thinking about it more, I've added a [tag:android-4.0] ← [tag:android-ics] synonym so when typing "ics" it will at least show the proper Android tag too...

Comment: @AlEverett: They'd still been showing up fairly regularly, but I'd adopted that tag and was checking it for new questions showing up that needed retagging.