# Why is gingerbread a tag synonym for Android?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

Why is [gingerbread](/questions/tagged/gingerbread) a tag synonym for [android](/questions/tagged/android) when [eclair](/questions/tagged/eclair), [honeycomb](/questions/tagged/honeycomb), [jellybean](/questions/tagged/jellybean), etc., aren't.  Is this a mistake?

Comment: This doesn't look like a bug to me - it might not be right, but that doesn't automatically make it a bug.

Comment: @Flexo Then where should I write about it in order to get someone to fix it? I can suggest synonyms but I can't revoke/vote away synonyms :)

Comment: Here is the right place, I was just explaining the tag edit I made.

Comment: Related: [Merge and synonymize Android version tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131503)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since those tags are version tags, and have specific differences, it is probably inappropriate for [gingerbread](/questions/tagged/gingerbread) to be a synonym of [android](/questions/tagged/android).  Questions for any of the specific versions should be tagged with that version along with [android](/questions/tagged/android).

Comment: Based on the android eco system I'd say none. Android went from alpha -> beta -> 1.0 and forward. 1.5 was called cupcake.

Comment: So when will this get fixed? And by who?

Comment: @Warpzit, it will take a mod to fix that, and it's not always easy to get their attention and interest.  Maybe you could bounty this question.

Comment: then why not create honeycomb ,icecreamsandwhich also synonyms ?

Comment: @Warpzit I removed the gingerbread->android synonym. Feel free to award the bounty to Lance here, since his answer is really what drove the decision.