# Should we synonymize version tags to code names and not the other way around?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

### Note

I started this question thinking specifically about the Jelly Bean synonym issue, as exposed below, but then I realized that it can probably be generalized.

I think we should always synonymize versions to code names and not the other way around. While it can happen for different versions to share the same code name, the opposite seems quite unlikely.

Another approach could be to use both version numbers and code names in the tag name, as [suggested by Al Everett](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203969/should-we-synonymize-version-tags-to-code-names-and-not-the-other-way-around#comment650835_203969) in the comments. This has been done in [Android Enthusiast](https://android.stackexchange.com/), where for instance Android 4.3 questions are tagged [`[4.3-jelly-bean]`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4.3-jelly-bean).

On StackOverflow tags like [android-4.3-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/android-4.3-jelly-bean) or [osx-10.9-mavericks](/questions/tagged/osx-10.9-mavericks) would be a good way of tackling this issue, IMO.

---

#### Original question

As a follow up to [Merge and synonymize Android version tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131503/merge-and-synonymize-android-version-tags) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203882/synonym-request-kitkat-android-4-4, we currently have

[android-4.2](/questions/tagged/android-4.2) ← [jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/jelly-bean), [android-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/android-jelly-bean)

but Google kindly named Android 4.3 Jelly Bean as well.

Currently [android-4.3](/questions/tagged/android-4.3) has no synonyms, but it has the same exact rights as [android-4.2](/questions/tagged/android-4.2) to be pointed by [jellybean](/questions/tagged/jellybean) (and [android-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/android-jelly-bean)).

So we have this situation

[jellybean](/questions/tagged/jellybean)
| ====> [android-4.2](/questions/tagged/android-4.2)
|  - - - -> [android-4.3](/questions/tagged/android-4.3)
|  - - - -> [android-4.1](/questions/tagged/android-4.1) (hypothetically, since such tag doesn't exist)

Since it makes no sense for a synonym to point to two different tags, how can we handle this?

Should we invert the synonym relationship and have

[android-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/android-jelly-bean) ← [android-4.2](/questions/tagged/android-4.2)
[android-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/android-jelly-bean) ← [android-4.3](/questions/tagged/android-4.3)
[android-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/android-jelly-bean) ← [jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/jelly-bean)

instead?

Comment: I would prefix the codenames with "android-" though. And in addition, make sure the excerpt tag wiki lists all the applicable android version numbers for easy reference.

Comment: Agreed, I edited my question a bit and I also noticed that `[jelly-bean]` is synonymized but `[jellybean]` is not.

Comment: I'd say these are excellent points not to have jelly-bean or kitkat tags.

Comment: @Bart not sure. Code names are very common when referring to a version  and I wouldn't feel completely ok in eradicating such tags. Also, due to their popularity, removing them would be useless, unless they are blacklisted. And I hardly doubt all code names tags will be considered as good candidates for blacklisting.

Comment: Then at most I'd keep them completely separate. Because whatever synonymization you'd choose, you would end up with a less than ideal situation.

Comment: Over at [android.se] we've "solved" this issue by using version numbers with codenames, e.g., 4.1-jellybean, 4.2-jellybean, 4.4-kitkat

Comment: Ooh, that's not a bad one @AlEverett.

Comment: @Bart I don't think keeping them separated would lead to any benefit. For instance, `[android-4.4]` and `[kitkat]` clearly refer to the same thing. If they exist they should be synonymized, in one direction or the other, IMO.

Comment: @AlEverett that's a clever solution. I would like to see it applied on StackOveflow too.

Comment: Unforunately, the Android Enthusiasts solution to the problem doesn't (and shouldn't IMHO) apply to Stack Overflow. Android anything is implied there, but not at Stack Overflow. Tagging in that manner would only leave the site littered with very cryptic tag names. Imagine if _every_ set of tags in Stack Overflow did that. It would do more harm I'm afraid.

Comment: @JeffMercado, I understand the concern, but `[android-4.3-jelly-bean]` doesn't look cryptic to me.

Comment: Right, that's a nice compromise. I was more concerned about the introduction of the [4.1-jellybean] tag and friends.

Comment: @JeffMercado I agree. I like the approach, but I never suggested to copy such tags verbatim, as you can see in my question ;)

Comment: @animuson I've seen your edit. Why [jellybean] shouldn't be synonymzed to [android-jelly-bean]? It's used in the exact same way as `[jelly-bean]`

Comment: @GabrielePetronella http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147233/should-we-get-rid-of-all-the-tag-synonyms-which-differ-by-only-one-or-more-hyphe

Comment: @animuson thanks, makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been lingering long enough. I went ahead with the method already utilized on Android Enthusiasts and just appended the codename to each version tag, leaving us with:

- [android-1.5-cupcake](/questions/tagged/android-1.5-cupcake)
- [android-1.6-donut](/questions/tagged/android-1.6-donut)
- [android-2.0-eclair](/questions/tagged/android-2.0-eclair)
- [android-2.1-eclair](/questions/tagged/android-2.1-eclair)
- [android-2.2-froyo](/questions/tagged/android-2.2-froyo)
- [android-2.3-gingerbread](/questions/tagged/android-2.3-gingerbread)
- [android-3.0-honeycomb](/questions/tagged/android-3.0-honeycomb)
- [android-4.0](/questions/tagged/android-4.0) -- This is for Ice Cream Sandwich, but that codename is too long. I considered using "ics" but wanted opinions before changing it to that.
- [android-4.2-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/android-4.2-jelly-bean)
- [android-4.3-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/android-4.3-jelly-bean)
- [android-4.4-kitkat](/questions/tagged/android-4.4-kitkat)

Let me know if I missed any. Also, all of the original "**android-x.x**" tags were synonymized into their respective new tags.

[jellybean](/questions/tagged/jellybean) has been destroyed as well.

Comment: +100 This is definitely the way to go. We didn't really get any information from a generic "jellybean" tag that we didn't already get from a version tag.