# Tag Synonyms for [java1.5] -> [java-5] and [java1.6] -> [java-6]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

I've just seen edits to the tag wikis for [java1.5](/questions/tagged/java1.5) and [java1.6](/questions/tagged/java1.6) and thought "Strange, there are already [java-5](/questions/tagged/java-5) and [java-6](/questions/tagged/java-6) tags with perfectly cromulent tag wikis; why is there duplicate work?"

And I saw that there are a few questions (24 and 53 respectively) tagged with those tags. I suggest them as tag synonyms but experience tells me that those don't get votes, so I'm asking for votes (for [**both**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-5/synonyms) [**tags**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-6/synonyms)) *or* mod interaction in getting those synonyms in the system.

Normally I'd just retag those questions, but I'm pretty sure that those tags would pop up again pretty quickly.

And **yes**: *Java 1.5 is the same as Java 5* and *[Java 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053061/is-java-1-6-the-same-as-jdk-6) is the same as [Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean)*.

*Update:* There are still not votes on the synonyms, people seem to agree that they should be here, but no one seems to be able to vote.

Comment: Something like my question about [android related tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122538/tags-for-android-related-api-versions). I think that's a good idea.

Comment: +1 for using cromulent correctly in the real world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synonyms are now in place. If there are no objections, I'll do the merge later today; I don't see any obvious issues preventing it.

Edit: Merged.